# What's going on with 2 Majors mirroring each other?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell-2017

In a scene where Major goes home (I think) to have a moment to herself, there is also a double (or a "holographic" copy) copying her movements but not like in a mirror, but rather both moving each one's left hand:

[image]
[image]

The camera in this scene starts panning from this frame, where some sort of holographic display is seen (maybe this orange display device is an indicator of what may be going on):

[image]

We've seen holographic projections of people multiple times in the movie, and this might be one of them. In some scenes people think these projections are real, like with the interrogated garbage man and in the scene where Cutter asks Aramaki to tell Batou to stop *<sub>(while Cutter being a projection, and Batou probably thinking he could intimidate Cutter by stepping up closer? But Cutter certainly knew his body was just a projection in Aramaki's office, so he couldn't be harmed, so then why… ok this is weird, moving on.)</sub>*

Form the anime universe of Ghost in the Shell, we know that one person can control multiple bodies at the same time, and the bodies may mirror each other's movements, as well as move asynchronously. In this movie, whenever somebody controls another body, they have a visible wired connection at least on one side (controlling body or the controlled).

I didn't catch any pieces of information which would explain what exactly is going on in this scene. Was it a "hologram"? Or was it another body? Or perhaps it was some visual glitch -like effect that Major's been having? Or is it something else?